# Is there a way to move pages with the onenote API?

Tags: onenote, onenote-api

I am trying to reorganise a large onenote file imported from Evernote. Because of the very different ways the two programs handle tags, the import ended up a conceptual mess.

So now I would like to find and select all the notes (around 2,000) which have a particular tag and move them to a fresh notebook. I think I can see how to find all the pages with a particular tag through the API. But I can't see anyway to move the found page somewhere else.

Is there a way to do what I want? Or would I have to copy the content of every found page into a new one and then delete the old one?

Answer (score -1):

There is no Move Api. But you could follow a 2 step process -

1. Copy Api (for Page) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/onenote-copy
2. Delete Api (for Page) - https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/onenotedev/2015/07/08/now-in-production-delete-page/

Comment: Thank you @amol-natu. This would be an excellent answer if it worked on consumer onedrive (which is what I have), but it doesn't: from the linked site


`Copy functionality is currently supported for Office 365 personal, site, and unified group notebooks, but not for consumer notebooks on OneDrive.`


Since I didn't specify what version of onenote I was using I can only be grateful that you took the trouble to answer